# Simple autoupdate. How can I run the installer and delete it after it's complete?

Tags: installation, auto-update

I want to create a simple autoupdate that downloads the new version of my software (in a temp folder), runs the installer (I'm using Innosetup) which will take care of closing my application and then, after the setup is complete, I would like to remove the installer file.

What's the best approach to do that?

I saw there are a number of libraries that take care of everything but I have written almost all the code used to check for updates and I'd just need to be able to run the installer.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NAppUpdate](http://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate) framework to achieve that quite easily.

Check this out: http://www.sjurvarhaug.com/nappupdate-to-automatically-download-and-execute-installer